# Are Data Explorer full-text column indexes planned?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-explorer

Is it a possibility that full-text indexes will be eventually added to certain columns in the Data Explorer? I perfectly understand that SO servers are under a heavy load, and this would add significantly to disk use, but on the other hand, full-text queries are more efficient once the index is built and maintained. Text querying is a very powerful tool, and, given that, for one, regular SO search does not index comments, would be the to-go way for searching in them.

Currently, an attempt to use the `CONTAINS()` and `FREETEXT()` T-SQL predicates on `comments.text` results in an error:

```
select top(100) id [Comment Link], text
from comments
where freetext (text, 'attribute package')
order by score desc
```

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'comments' because it is not full-text indexed.

Was this feature considered? And if it was, is it planned? A question about one of the predicates [came up last time in 2014](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/237866/178251) (and was only incidental, stemming from an incorrect attempted use of `CONTAINS` instead of `LIKE`), so I think it would not be too much of a nuisance to ask about it specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, we have no plans to add full-text searching in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). [Full-text search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) is an expensive process. With the sizes of some of databases and since we refresh the public data explorer weekly, it would result in far too much overhead to put in place.